# PHP parse facebook json

Tags: php, facebook

I've search Stack Overflow and Google for an answer but not luck. I'm trying to get the value of each of the locale with php in the following sample (facebook graph api). Any help would be appreciated.

```
"data": [
    {
      "id": "123456789/insights/page_fans_locale/lifetime",
      "name": "page_fans_locale",
      "period": "lifetime",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": {
            "en_US": 33975,
            "fr_CA": 6906,
            "fr_FR": 6105,
            "en_GB": 5647
          },
          "end_time": "2012-03-14T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
          "value": {
            "en_US": 33992,
            "fr_CA": 6906,
            "fr_FR": 6107,
            "en_GB": 5648
          },
          "end_time": "2012-03-15T07:00:00+0000"
        }, 
}
```

Comment: This what i've tried so far :
 
$fb_response = json_decode($graph_url);
 
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($fb_response));
 
 foreach($iterator as $key=>$value) {
   echo "<b>".$key."</b><br />".$value."<br />";
}

Comment: With this i can have all keys and values but i'm triyng to have only locales and values.

Answer (score 0):

First, this fragment is broken. `data` is a array not a JavaScript object. 
Take the correct fragment and analyze data correctly. The best option is:

```
json_decode();
```

[Here is how to use it.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)